# selenium timeout on Heroku

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, heroku, webdriverwait

I tried to build a flask+selenium web on Heroku , so I went through a lot of step , I got my website setup , but when I tried to call an API that include selenium , I got an error from Selenium:

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Here's the part of my selenium python code , I tried to login to instagram.

```
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") 
    chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1400,800')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=chrome_options)
    ig_username = os.environ.get("IG_USERNAME")
    ig_password = os.environ.get("IG_PASSWORD")
    
    web = 'https://www.instagram.com'; 
    browser.get(web)
    print ("Headless Chrome with custom window-size")
    size = browser.get_window_size()
    print("Window size: width = {}px, height = {}px".format(size["width"], size["height"]))
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(browser,10)
        ig_account_ele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, //*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input)))
        print(ig_account_ele)
        ig_account_ele.send_keys(ig_username)
```

The code will return timeout error  at first element that I am trying to search.I even tried it on google.com and other element like span, it still won't work.
It's all fine when I run the code on local!!! ,but when it's deployed to Heroku, it will return timeout error or unable to locate element when I test the code  with find_element_by_id,
so I assume there must be something wrong with selenium , but I don't have any way to solve it, seems it is also hard to see what's going on with chromedirver when running headless mode on Heroku...

Comment: Ever figure this out? Same issue. It just times out. Works fine locally.

Comment: I figure this out , the problem is on Facebook policy , the website is anti-script, I used console to find out when I go to Instagram website , it shows there's something wrong please try again, and I google it , the possible reason is that you are using script, so it's a dead end