# how to take screen shot using selenium WebDriver on Heroku

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, heroku, screenshot

I had a python selenium code  that is working on local but when I deployed it on Heroku it will return timeoutException error, here's the link

[selenium timeout on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68166536/selenium-timeout-on-heroku)

so I want to see what's going on when the ChromeDriver is loading, but the thing is I am new to Heroku , I want to know when I take screenshot on remote chromdwriver using selenium where  is the file be saved or is there a way to see it .